# Precisely how to update Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, updates

On an ordinary AWS Ubuntu instance, I see exactly this:

[image]

I believe the three possible commands involved are

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

So there are 21 possible permutations.

In spite of searching the vast discussion on this (try it) I cannot find the definitive answer!

What is the correct permutation?

- Which commands
- in which order,

definitively should one enter in that situation?

Comment: On my Linux systems (Ubuntu and Kali) I do the first command (sudo apt-get update) to get a list of updates, allow it to finish, and then to the second command (sudo apt-get upgrade) to do the download and update. That works well for me.

Comment: There isn’t a correct or incorrect order.

Comment: @Ramhound , you're probably an expert and that's perhaps obvious to you.  But.  If you search on this, there is a HUGE amount of debate about whether that is true or not.  Also, it is unclear if all three are even needed.  Hence the question!

Comment: It's astonishing there are no experts with opinions on this !

Answer (score 1):

I often use this command to update my Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Here is the detailed information from the source:

> It will ask for a password. You can use your account’s password. You
>   won’t see characters on the screen while typing, so keep on typing
>   your password and hit enter. This will update the packages in Ubuntu.
>
> Now let me explain the above command.
>
> It’s actually not a single command, it’s a combination of two
>   commands. The && is a way to combine two commands such that the second
>   command runs only when the previous command ran successfully.
>
> The “-y” in the end automatically enters “yes” when the command “apt
>   upgrade” ask for your confirmation before installing updates.
>
> Note that you can also use the two commands separately, one by one:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt upgrade
> ```
>
> It will take a little longer, because you have to wait for one command
>   to finish and then enter the second command.
>
> **Explanation: sudo apt update**
>
> This command updates the local database of available packages. If you
>   don’t run this command, the local database won’t be updated and your
>   system will not know if there are any new versions of packages
>   available.
>
> This is why, when you run the “sudo apt update” command, you’ll see
>   lots of URLs in the output. The command fetches the package
>   information from the respective repositories (the URLs you see in the
>   output).
>
> [image]
>
> At the end of the command, it tells you how many packages can be
>   upgraded. You can see these packages by running the following command:
>
> ```
> apt list --upgradable
> ```
>
> **Explanation: sudo apt upgrade**
>
> This command matches the versions of installed packages with the local
>   database. It collects all of them, and then it will list those
>   packages that have a newer version available. At this point, it will
>   ask if you want to upgrade the installed packages to the newer
>   version.
>
> You can type “yes,” or “y,” or just press enter to confirm the
>   installation of updates.
>
> So the bottom line is that “sudo apt update” checks for the
>   availability of new package versions, while “sudo apt upgrade”
>   actually installs the new versions.

upgrade
   upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages
   currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in
   /etc/apt/sources.list. Packages currently installed with new
   versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no
   circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages
   not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of
   currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without
   changing the install status of another package will be left at
   their current version. An update must be performed first so that
   apt-get knows that new versions of packages are available.

> dist-upgrade
>
> dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
>   also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
>   of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
>   it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
>   expense of less important ones if necessary. So, dist-upgrade
>   command may remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file
>   contains a list of locations from which to retrieve desired package
>   files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a mechanism for overriding
>   the general settings for individual packages.

Source: [How To Update Ubuntu With Command Line And Software Updater](https://bytebitebit.com/1704/update-ubuntu-with-command-line-and-software-updater/)

Comment: this really does not address sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
expense of less important ones if necessary. So, dist-upgrade
command may remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file
contains a list of locations from which to retrieve desired package
files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a mechanism for overriding
the general settings for individual packages.